# C / C++ Matrix Multiplication Order

Tags: c++, math, opengl, glm-math

In mathematics, if three matrices, 'A', 'B' and 'C' are multiplied, such that a fourth matrix 'D = A * B * C', then the order must be computed *right to left*. Using parentheses to clarify, the previous statement is exactly equivalent to the following; 'D = (A * (B * C))'.

You can see how this applies for the expression '{ M = A * B * C * D } == { M = (A * (B * (C * (D)))) }', which is another example.

In C, C++, I ran a test using division to check the order in which operations are done in C and C++.

There is probably a better way of doing this my compiling assembly code, however:

```
float a = 1.0;
float b = 2.0;
float c = 2.0;
float ans = a / b / c;
printf("answer is %f\n", ans);
```

This gives the output:

```
answer is 0.25
```

This suggests to me that if I were to create a class to represent a matrix, then the order of multiplication would be *left to right*, the reverse of what is desired, since the example with floating point operations and division is evaluated left to right since the three operations have equal precedence.

In the OpenGL Mathematics library, GLM, matrix operations are computed in the correct order, without the requirement for parentheses.

How is operator*() made to behave in this way?

## Edit

Err, yeah, so it doesn't actually matter as it has been pointed out to me. In which case my question becomes "is it possible to change the order"? (Maybe I am sleepy?)

Comment: I think you're wrong about the matrix multiplication, it is in fact associative.  [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#General).

Comment: Yes, but it is not easy.  Look up expression templates: basically store the expression tree and only evaluate it at assignment, allowing arbitrary transformations of the tree.

Comment: To make the question valid, change matrix multiplication to vector (cross) product. That is not associative, and there are much more formulas a×(b×c) out there than (a×b)×c, so that right-to-left associativity would be natural. I would not advise, however, to rely on operator associativity but to use parentheses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ `/` and binary `*` operators are both left-to-right associative.  End of story - there's no way to change that.

[Matrix multiplication *is* associative](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Matrix_Multiplication_is_Associative), though, so that shouldn't affect you.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is simple: matrix multiplication is associative; scalar division is *not*. `(A / (B / C))` is not the same as `((A / B) / C)`. But `(A * (B * C))` is the same as `((A * B) * C)`, for both matrix and scalar multiplication.

So the order that C++ calls operators in just doesn't matter for matrix multiplication.

Comment: C++ (and glsl) multiplications and matrix multiplication are NOT associative, since multiplying the operand in different order can change the results due to approximations and precision issues. `(A * (B * C))` is the same as `((A * B) * C)` in math, but not in C++ nor in glsl.
Moreover if C is a vector instead of a matrix, the two solutions will have a different number of multiplications.